# Vue : Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...version":"0.5.0","dev'

Tags: vue.js, npm

I am Learning Vue JS. Planning to develop application on it. Initially I installed Vue by

```
npm install vue-cli -g
```

But some of good Friend told me that this is Depreciated. Its there in the documentation also. 
[Vue Javascript with npm install command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61633856/vue-javascript-with-npm-install-command)

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html

But unable to install Vue by cmd:

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
```

this gives me Error as :

```
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...version":"0.5.0","dev'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Abhilash\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-13T12_14_23_300Z-debug.log
```

What may be the Error ? How overcome from this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try cleaning `npm` cache and then install vue

```
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g  @vue/cli
```

Comment: Happy to help :)